# fast compact register using sse

Tags: c++, sse, sse4

I am trying to figure out how to use sse _mm_shuffle_epi8 to compact a 128-bit register.

Let's say, I have an input  variable

```
__m128i target
```

which is basically 8 16-bits, indicated as:

```
a[0], a[1] ... a[7].  // each slot is 16 bits
```

my output is called:

```
__m128i output
```

Now I have a bit-vector of size 8:

```
char bit_mask // 8 bits, i-th bit each indicate if
              // the corresponding a[i] should be included
```

OK, how can I get the final result based on the bit_mask and the input target?

assume my bitvector is:

```
[0 1 1 0 0 0 0 0]
```

then I want to result to be:

```
output = [a1, a2 , ... ]
```

Any known way to do this using _mm_shuffle_epi8?

Assume I use a lookup array:
_mm_shuffle_epi8(a, mask_lookup[bitvector]);

How do I create the array?

Comment: So, you want to pick out, say, bit 5 out of each of the 8 of your 16-bit numbers?

Answer (score 4):

Simple and very fast, but requires 4KB of table space:

```
_mm_shuffle_epi8(a, mask_lookup[bitvector]);
```

where you simply store all 256 possible shuffle masks in a table indexed by the bitvector.

Comment: How do I create the lookup array? Do I have to manually create that?

Comment: @WhatABeautifulWorld: A sane person would write a simple program to generate it.